# How to wrap text in a dataframe's table (converted to .png)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, datatable, mplfinance

[image]

I am having an issue where I cannot format my tables.  The text is too long to just edit the dimensions or the text size.  How can I quickly change this so you can see all the text when I have the data for each column more filled in?  I am looking for a wrap text kind of function but I don't know if that is possible the way I'm doing it.  Is there another way you'd recommend? I'm changing the table into a .png to insert into an Excel file.  It has to be a .png so it's an object and doesn't mess with the size of the rows and columns in Excel.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import xlsxwriter as xl
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd 
import datetime as dt
import mplfinance as mpf 
import pandas_datareader 
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
yf.pdr_override()
import numpy as np

Individualreport = "C:\\Users\\Ashley\\FromPython.xlsx"
Ticklist = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Ashley\\Eyes Trial Data Center.xlsx",sheet_name='Tickers', header=None)
stocks = Ticklist.values.ravel()
PipelineData = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Ashley\\Eyes Trial Data Center.xlsx", sheet_name='Pipeline', header=None)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(Individualreport, engine='xlsxwriter')

for i in stocks:

    #write pipeline data
    t = PipelineData.loc[(PipelineData[0]==i)]
    print(t)
   
    def render_mpl_table(data, col_width=10, row_height=1, font_size=10, wrap=True,
                     header_color='#40466e', row_colors=['#f1f1f2', 'w'], edge_color='w',
                     bbox=[0, 0, 1, 1], header_columns=0,
                     ax=None, **kwargs):
        if ax is None:
            size = (np.array(data.shape[::-1]) + np.array([0, 1])) * np.array([col_width, row_height])
            fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=size)
            ax.axis('off')
        mpl_table = ax.table(cellText=data.values, bbox=bbox, colLabels=data.columns, **kwargs)
        mpl_table.auto_set_font_size(False)
        #mpl_table.set_fontsize(font_size)

        for k, cell in mpl_table._cells.items():
            cell.set_edgecolor(edge_color)
            if k[0] == 0 or k[1] < header_columns:
                cell.set_text_props(weight='bold', color='w')
                cell.set_facecolor(header_color)
            else:
                cell.set_facecolor(row_colors[k[0]%len(row_colors) ])
        return ax.get_figure(), ax


    fig,ax = render_mpl_table(t, header_columns=0, col_width=2.0)
    fig.savefig(str(i)+'pipe.png')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I needed to use an additional package, haven't tried with this example, but worked in another similar example I did.

```
from textwrap import wrap
label = ("label text that is getting put in the graph")
label = [ '\n'.join(wrap(l, 20)) for l in label ] 

#20 is number of characters per line
```